# Load images and labels as filenames in Tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a question that i got a data downloaded in my disk in one folder , I want to load them to my Jupyter notebook to train it. However, The labels of each image is embedded in the file name, formatted like this [age]*[gender]*[race]_[date&time].jpg

I would like to load both the images and labels and split them into training, validation and testing dataset.

I am a beginner in Tensorflow and deep-learning,

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please try to clarify your question ? Is this actually about tensorflow or reading files ?  Posting code will also help everyone better understand your  question.

Comment: it is about reading the files using any library such as tensorflow, so i can train it letter using CNN.